# Solving a matrix equation with constraints on the answer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I'm currently trying to solve a matrix equation of the form Ax = b where A is an NxN square matrix and x,b are 1xN vectors. However, I require that all the elements x[i] be non-negative.

Imposing this constraint means that a solution may well not be possible (if you're doing this analytically there is only 1 unique solution, which if it has negative entries puts me out of luck) but there must be a way to find an x that gets as close as possible? I'm unsure what this is formally called so I've had little luck searching.

What I have so far:

```
N=10

A = np.random.rand(N,N)
B = np.random.rand(N)

A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
x = np.dot( A_inv, B )

x=
array([ 0.42216451,  1.70270083, -1.54040488,  2.18724233,  2.04278932, -1.76074253])
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is called [non-negative least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) and [scipy supports it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html).

Without testing, usage would look like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import nnls

N=10

A = np.random.rand(N,N)
B = np.random.rand(N)
x, rnorm = nnls(A, B)
```

The algorithm is quite old and highly trusted, but only works for small-to-medium scale problems (as it calculates `A.T * A` internally). If you got huge problems (sparse problem with millions of variables), you should try some custom-formulation based on [L-BFGS-B](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html) or better: a custom (iterative) algorithm.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. The final implementation will be many (~1000) small (N~5) solves so this should work perfectly.

Comment: Then the algorithmic-base of nnls is perfectly suited (fast, robust and high accuracy).